# Star Trek 50th anniversary convention(s)?

Tags: discussion

Are any fellow scifi.se Trekkies planning to attend a **Star Trek convention** in 2016?  If so:

- Is the one in Las Vegas in April 2016 (Creation Entertainment) the "official" 50th Anniversary convention?  (If not, which one is?)
- How far in advance should one acquire tickets?

Since this is meta and  not the main site, allow me to say *thanks in advance*.

Comment: The event is certainly described as the "Official" Star Trek event; http://www.creationent.com/cal/st_lasvegas.html

Comment: Does "official" mean *official*?   I imagine that, armed with sufficient quid, any event agency can have their gala licensed as official.  Although scrolling through the site, it does seem their past events have attracted a significant number of Trek actors.  :-)

Comment: I dunno whether you can call it official if it's not licensed.

Comment: I mean, maybe all one needs to do is pay Paramount / CBS enough money and...voila...licensed.