# Is it okay to post obituary posts on meta for those who never were on a Sci-Fi or Fantasy work?

Tags: discussion, scope, closing-questions, in-memoriam, meta

As you may know, [obituary posts aren't allowed on Movies and TV Meta SE](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4855/should-movies-tv-meta-have-obituary-posts-for-deaths-of-famous-cineasts-simil), and here, the scope is about Sci-Fi & Fantasy works.

So is it allowed to post obituaries for well-known filmmakers, actors/actresses, scriptwriters, etc. who have passed away recently *but* weren't part of any Sci-Fi or Fantasy work?

Comment: It seems pretty obviously off-topic; why would you think that wouldn't be the case?  Not all posts/questions have a home on SE; that's simply a truism.

Comment: It's quite rare for you not to be able to find *some* scifi or fantasy connection, no matter how tenuous.

Comment: "As you know obituary posts aren't allowed on Movies and TV Meta SE" - I didn't know that, but I've learned it now.

Comment: @Randal'Thor Well, I was going to write it as *as you may know*. But since I also wanted to write about this site too (the very next sentence) I thought it would be rude to use *may*.

Comment: Related: [How do we judge whether a Sci-fi/Fantasy figure is important enough to get an "In Memoriam" meta post?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10475/7957)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's explicitly asking about posting things unrelated to scifi & f at all. By definition thus is neither the site or meta for this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In a word, no. Per page zero of the [Tour](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour).

> Science Fiction & Fantasy Stack Exchange is a question and answer site
> for science fiction and fantasy enthusiasts. It's built and run by you
> as part of the Stack Exchange network of Q&A sites. With your help,
> we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every
> **question about science fiction or fantasy**.

If your question doesn't even tangentially touch on the subject of sci-fi or fantasy, we're not really here for you, even if there's nowhere else in the network. And that goes for [Meta-RIP posts](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10444/20774) too.

---

That all being said, if you can find *any* relevant connection, that's entirely fine. They don't need to be a 'sci-fi-or-fantasy actor' exclusively, just someone who's been in something that meets the site topic.

Comment: I imagine the obituary of an actor or filmaker who is only *tenuously* related to scifi&f will be heavily downvoted though.